# Value of determinant using trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry, determinant

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text { If } \mathrm{a}=\sin \frac{\pi}{7}+\sin \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\sin \frac{3 \pi}{7}, \mathrm{~b}=\cos \frac{\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\cos \frac{3 \pi}{7}, \mathrm{c}=\tan \frac{\pi}{7}+\tan \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\tan \frac{3 \pi}{7} \\
& \text { then }\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
6 a^2+10 b^2 & 8 a b+25 b c & 10 a c+30 a b \\
9 a b-8 b c & 12 b^2-20 c^2 & 15 b c-24 a c \\
12 a c-10 a b & 16 b c-25 a c & 20 c^2-30 a^2
\end{array}\right| \text { equals } \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

So far I have been to find values of a, b & c like this
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{aligned}
 a&=\sin \frac{\pi}{7}+\sin \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\sin \frac{3 \pi}{7} \\
& =\frac{\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi}{14}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{14}\right)} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}+\frac{\pi}{7}\right) \\
& =\frac{\sin \left(\frac{3 \pi}{14}\right) \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right)}{\sin \frac{\pi}{14}}=\frac{\sin \frac{3 \pi}{14} \cdot \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi}{14}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{14}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sin \left(\frac{6 \pi}{14}\right)}{2 \sin \frac{\pi}{14}}=\frac{1}{2} \cot \frac{\pi}{7} \\
 b&=\cos \frac{\pi}{7}+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\cos \frac{3 \pi}{7}=\frac{\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi}{1 m}\right) \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{7}\right)}{\cos \frac{\pi}{7}}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin \frac{6 \pi}{7}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{7}}=\frac{1}{2} \tan \frac{\pi}{7} \\
&
\end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
 c&=\tan \frac{\pi}{7}+\tan \frac{2 \pi}{7}+\tan \frac{3 \pi}{7}=\sin \frac{\pi}{7} \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7}+\cos \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \sin \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7} \\
& +\cos \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \frac{\sin 3 \pi}{7} \\
& \cos \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7} \\
& =\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{7}+\frac{2 \pi}{7}+\frac{3 \pi}{7}\right)+\sin \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \sin \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cdot \sin \frac{3 \pi}{7}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7}} \\
& =\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{7}+\sin \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \sin \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cdot \sin \frac{3 \pi}{7}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \cdot \cos \frac{3 \pi}{7}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: What's the source of this problem? Why this determinant?

Comment: this problem is from a test paper for JEE Advanced preparation.